# Weak property not zeroing using ARC

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have the following simple code for an object that holds a weak reference:

*// interface*

```
@interface GMWeakRefObj : NSObject
@property (weak) id object;
@end
```

*// implementation*

```
@implementation GMWeakRefObj 
@synthesize object;
@end
```

When I run the following test code it fails on the second assert:

```
NSData* d = [[NSData alloc] init];
GMWeakRefObj* weakRef = [[GMWeakRefObj alloc] init];
weakRef.object = d;
NSAssert(weakRef.object != nil, @"Reference wasn't assigned");
d = nil;
NSAssert(weakRef.object == nil, @"Reference wasn't zeroed"); // <-- FAIL
```

Aren't ARC weak references supposed to be zeroing? And if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of iOS/Mac OS are you using? The zeroing weak referencing runtime is only available on iOS 5/OS 10.7

Comment: I'm running this on the 5.0 simulator and the target has a deployment target of 5.0 so version mismatches shouldn't be an issue. Also I just tried this just using raw references (i.e. not properties) and the weak reference zeroed out without problems - so the mechanism does work just not for my property for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some custom class class instead of `NSData` for `d`, e.g. `MyData`. Implement `dealloc` method in it and set breakpoint in it. You will see, that `dealloc` is called by autorelease pool *after* the last `NSAssert`. Only after that week reference will become `nil`.

ADD:
Looks like I have to extend my answer to make it clear, why it works that way.
First, lets look at your example (from comments):

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] init];
__weak NSData* weakRef = data;
data = nil;
NSAssert(weakRef == nil, @"Failed to zero");
```

It works as expected, `weakRef` become `nil` after `data = nil`. The next example works too:

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] init];
__weak NSData* weakRef = data;
NSLog(@"%@", data);
data = nil;
NSAssert(weakRef == nil, @"Failed to zero");
```

But the last example doesn't work:

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] init];
__weak NSData* weakRef = data;
NSLog(@"%@", weakRef);
data = nil;
NSAssert(weakRef == nil, @"Failed to zero");
```

The only difference is that we use weak reference to output log. Why?

**(the rest of the answer can be wrong :) )**

Imaging that you `NSLog` (or any other function/selector we call before `data = nil`) rely on it's argument not to be `nil`. For example, it has "if (arg == nil) return;" at the very beginning.

In multithreaded environment weak reference *can* become `nil` *after* `if`.

So properly written function should look like:

```
  // ...
  T* local_arg = arg;   // NOTE: it is strong!
  if (local_arg == nil)
    return;
  // work with local_arg here, not with arg
  // ...
```

But usually we don't want to do it everywhere -- it will be ugly. So we want to be sure that arguments will not disappear somewhere in the middle. Compiler does it for us by autoreleasing weak reference.

So, it should be clear how, why your `GMWeakRefObj` test case doesn't work -- `weakRef` is autoreleased before calling `setObject` setter.

Comment: That does work, but I'm a little perplexed. If I write the following 
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] init];
    __weak NSData* weakRef = data;
    data = nil;
    NSAssert(weakRef == nil, @"Failed to zero");

The assert passes as expected. Is there somewhere that the rules are spelled out for when ARC autoreleases and when it releases immediately? Or is the standard practice to always assume autorelease?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation - it's much appreciated. One small lingering question though ;) I understand why the compiler would want to automate retaining a variable until a method is done with it but why use auto-release? Wouldn't retaining at the start of the method and releasing as it's about to return be a better (and more consistent way) to handle that?

Comment: @Mattia, I don't know :) actually the description is just IMHO, an example why compiler does such things. I think only compiler's source code can answer how it actually works.