# Can two weak variables create a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In ARC, if A hold a strong reference to B, and B holds a strong ref to A, there will be a retain cycle.

Will the code below also create a retain cycle?

```
    __weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
    [self doSomething:^{

        weakSelf.someVariable = YES;

        [weakSelf doSomething:^{

            weakSelf.someVariable = YES;
        }];

    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ARC the weakSelf pointer is copied, but since it's weak, the copy of the pointer will not cause the retain count to be increased. So no, it doesn't create a retain cycle.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't. In fact, if you dont retain the object and for some reason the block would be called after the `MyClass` object gets deallocated, you end up with a runtime crash

Comment: Why would it lead to a crash? Wouldn't `weakSelf` be set to `nil` automatically after the object gets deallocated?

Comment: I'm not really sure right now what exactly was going on behind the scenes, but I recently had a crash in a very similar scenario and I did in fact end up creating a temporary retain cycle. This answer [Weak property not zeroing using ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9099661/384916) gives a little bit more info on the weak pointer thing...