# Objective C - Self Zeroing weak pointer unexpected behaviour

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have recently upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite and now my unit tests are failing. The problem boiled down to a typo in a weak pointer to string content. Please see the following sample code:

```
NSString* value1;
NSString* value2;
__weak NSString* weakValue1;
__weak NSString* weakValue2;
NSMutableString* resultText = [NSMutableString new];

@autoreleasepool
{
    value1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello: %d", 1];
    value2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello %d", 2];
    weakValue1 = value1;
    weakValue2 = value2;

    [resultText appendFormat: @"  value1 = %@", weakValue1];
    [resultText appendFormat: @"  value2 = %@", weakValue2];

    value1 = nil;
    value2 = nil;
}
[resultText appendFormat: @"  value1 = %@", weakValue1];
[resultText appendFormat: @"  value2 = %@", weakValue2];

NSLog( @"resultText = %@", resultText );
```

The output of this code is:

```
resultText =   value1 = Hello: 1  value2 = Hello 2  value1 = (null)  value2 = Hello 2
```

I would have expected:

```
resultText =   value1 = Hello: 1  value2 = Hello 2  value1 = (null)  value2 = (null)
```

the second `value2` to also be `(null)` but it is not. Please notice the difference between the content of `value1` and `value2`. `value2` is missing the colon. I do not understand why `weakValue2` does not self zero when `value2` is set to `nil`. As soon as I put the colon back in the string I get the results I expect. I was not seeing this behaviour when running this code in Mavericks.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I noticed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096008/weak-property-not-zeroing-using-arc?rq=1) that the valid point of multithreading could cause a weak pointer to not self zero in time, but that is not what is happening here. Firstly, I am not multithreaded and I get the exact same result if I step through the code and view the variables rather than printing them with NSLog.

Comment: i ran this code and both `value1` and `value2` are nil for me (using iOS 8 sdk), i guess maybe its just not guaranteed that the weak reference will lose its object immediately.

Comment: Build for MacOS, I have same behaviour.

Comment: I was not seeing this behaviour when my computer was running Mavericks. I updated to Yosemite and recompiled my code (build for MacOS) and that's when the problems started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSString it is not concrete class, it is interface and factory for many other classes.

I've found that value1 is instance of class __NSCFString, but value2 is instance of class NSTaggedPointerString. Class NSTaggedPointerString does not support retain and release (I try to inject some blocks to it methods).

If you print retainCount for this instance, you'll get that  result:

```
po [value2 retainCount] //18446744073709551615
```

If you remove symbol ":" from format, you'll get this result:

```
 resultText =   value1 = Hello 1  value2 = Hello 2  value1 = Hello 1  value2 = Hello 2
```

It's happened because above strings is instances of NSTaggedPointerString class. I think it is very strange behaviour.

P.S.

If you add ":" to value2 string, you'll get result:

```
resultText =   value1 = Hello: 1  value2 = Hello: 2  value1 = (null)  value2 = (null)
```

:)

**UPD**

If length of string less then 8, then it string will be cached to memory.

**UPD-2**

I've changed code to:

```
value1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Heo: %d", 1];
    value2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Heo: %d", 1];
    if (value2 == value1)
    {
        NSLog(@"same strings");
    }
```

I've had result: "same strings"

Comment: Yes, it is very strange, and I also added a colon to the second string to make it work. That is why it is so strange. What does a colon in a string have to do with anything.

Comment: btw, retainCount is not available in ARC. You would need to use CFGetRetainCount()

Comment: you can use it in debugger (then debugger's stoped your code): po [obj method]

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer now that you've updated it to include the string length notes. That is indeed what was causing it. Thank you for finding that.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Thanks for Debugger commands, it is very helpful to know:

Comment: `retainCount` (and `CFGetRetainCount()`) return effectively meaningless values.   Do not use them.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your use of weak references are colliding with implementation details of the system.

A weak reference will be nullified if-and-only-if the object it references is deallocated.   The timing therein is not actually guaranteed beyond that as long as the reference is non-NULL, the object referred to is still viable.

A weak reference to a singleton (true singleton that is never deallocated) will never be nullified.

NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, and a handful of other classes are implemented as singletons for some values some of the time.   Or a lot of the time, depending on the platform.

Thus, a weak reference to an instance of one of these classes may or may not be nullified because the instance may actually be a singleton.

Note that tagged pointers are, effectively, singletons by definition.

To fix?

**Don't create weak references to system primitive/value classes.**

Comment: Can you add some links to tagged pointers in objective-c (to see specification)? Here problem with different behaviour, that based on the string length. Can you add some link that describe this behaviour of NSString?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov The implementation details are effectively opaque and may vary from platform to platform, version to version.   The runtime source is available.  Long and short;  if the low order bit is set on a reference to an object, then the object is treated as a tagged pointer & the "address" of the object is actually the object itself (i.e. there is no allocation). So, it isn't really a singleton, but there is no allocation, nothing to deallocate, and weak references will never be nullified because of this.https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Comment: Thank you for good reference! It is very helpful information.