# How I can avoid caching of NSString instances in Objective-C runtime?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, osx-yosemite

Objective-C can to cache short strings. If you run modified code from [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469750/objective-c-self-zeroing-weak-pointer-unexpected-behaviour), you'll get result, that strings is same (one instance) (Build for OS X Yosemite). How to avoid this behaviour?

```
NSString* value1;
NSString* value2;
__weak NSString* weakValue1;
__weak NSString* weakValue2;
NSMutableString* resultText = [NSMutableString new];

@autoreleasepool
{
    value1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Heo: %d", 1];
    value2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Heo: %d", 1];
    if (value2 == value1)
    {
        NSLog(@"same strings");
    }
    [self injectToString:value2];
    weakValue1 = value1;
    weakValue2 = value2;

    [resultText appendFormat: @"  value1 = %@", weakValue1];
    [resultText appendFormat: @"  value2 = %@", weakValue2];

    value1 = nil;
    value2 = nil;
}
[resultText appendFormat: @"  value1 = %@", weakValue1];
[resultText appendFormat: @"  value2 = %@", weakValue2];

NSLog( @"resultText = %@", resultText );
```

**UPD**

Problems:

1. (value2 == value1) = true, but if you change @"Heo: %d" to @"Hellow: %d", it'll return false.
2. weakValue1 and weakValue2 **do** **not** become nil (never), but if you change @"Heo: %d" to @"Hello: %d", then weakValue1 and weakValue2 **become** nil.  I think it is problem.

Comment: What is the problem exactly, and why?

Comment: Why is it a problem? You shouldn't be comparing instance pointers in 99% of cases anyway

Comment: Those are [tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html).  If the string is short enough it will stored entirely within a 64-bit pointer variable. In that case, there's nothing to allocate or deallocate.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I want to get "normal" string to send it as weak  pointer to other thread, for example. It is abstract issue. I thought that I can use alloc to avoid this behavior, but I mistake. I want to find solution, to achieve of quiet in universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about avoiding implementation details, so whatever you come up with *might* become obsolete, but there's two things I can think of that are very unlikely to change.

First, you can go full-on wacko and re-build the string:

```
@interface NSString (WSSUncached)

+ (instancetype)WSSUncachedStringWithString:(NSString *)s;

@end

@implementation NSString (WSSUncached)

+ (instancetype)WSSUncachedStringWithString:(NSString *)s
{
    NSMutableString * newS = [NSMutableString string];

    [s enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){0, [s length]}
                          options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                       usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                           [newS appendString:substring];
                       }];

    return newS; // or [NSString stringWithString:newS]; if you're feeling especially crazy
}

@end
```

---

This does not throw on the 10.9 SDK.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString * s = @"Hello, world!";
        NSCAssert([NSString WSSUncachedStringWithString:s] !=
                    [NSString WSSUncachedStringWithString:s],
                  @"No good: even constructed strings are cached.");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Variations on this are possible, of course: C array with ASCII values, or transfer to `NSData` first...

The more sensible option would probably be loading the strings from a file.

```
NSString * fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"Helloworld.txt"
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];
NSString * sameFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"Helloworld.txt"
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         error:NULL];
NSCAssert(fileString != sameFileString, @"Nope; file strings are cached too.");
```

Even with Helloworld.txt being empty, this assertion succeeds.